# Doctrine 2 Discriminator Inheritance Mapping leads to findBy methods not working

Tags: inheritance, doctrine, mapping, doctrine-orm, discriminator

i have 2 entities, one as a main super class which consist of the discrimators etc and one which extends this super class...  so that i can 
record all actions in one table called Action.

my discrimator entity:

```
namespace Entities\Members;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="actions")
 * @MappedSuperClass
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="action_type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"comments" = "Comments", "blog" = "Blog"})
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacksIndex
 */
class Action {

    /**
     * @Id 
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=300, nullable=true) */
    public $name;

    /** @Column(name="action_date", type="datetime", columnDefinition="datetime", nullable=false) */
    protected $action_date;

    /** @PrePersist */
    public function updated() {
        $this->action_date = new \DateTime("now");
    }

}
```

this is one my entities that i use to extend the above discrimator entity:

```
namespace Entities\Members;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="comments")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Comments extends Action {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="bigint",length=15)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(name="blog_id", type="integer", nullable=true) */
    protected $blog_id;

    /** @Column(name="comment", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $comment;

    /** @Column(name="comment_date", type="datetime", columnDefinition="datetime", nullable=true) */
    protected $comment_date;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Members",inversedBy="comments", cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $author;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->comment_date = $this->comment_date = new \DateTime("now");
    }

}
```

this works nicely when i persist the comments entity, e.g.

```
$entity = new Entities\Comments;
$entity->comment = "my new comment";
$this->em->persist($entity);
$this->em->flush();
```

when i persist, it adds the action successfully into the actions table...

however, i cannot use any findBy, findByOne methods anymore,, the return value of any result from these methods = null
now, when i edit the comments class and remove the 'extend from Action', the doctrine findby, findOneBy methods starts working
but it wont add to tmy discriminator table as its not extending that main Actions super class...

i need it to extend Actions and have the doctrine method such as find, findOneBy, etc to work also...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your query code.  I was interested in seeing how this all worked so I copied your entities then did a query with:

```
protected function testJoinedQuery()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\Comments');

    $entity = $repo->findOneBy(array('id' => 2));

    echo get_class($entity) . ' ' . $entity->getComment() . "\n";

}
```

Seemed to work just fine.  Were you trying to use the Actions repo?

You probably won't need this:

- @MappedSuperClass

But having it doesn't seem to hurt anything.

Comment: nope..  when i do get_class($entity)  , it prints out the actual class name this code is in..  BaseController  ?   but if i remove the  'extends Activity'   it prints out Entities/Comments  , so it works if you dont extend Actions..

Comment: its the same as yours:    $repo =  $this->_em->getRepository('Entities\Comments');
        
    $entity = $repo->findOneBy(array('name' => 'bars'));
    //$entity = $repo->findOneById(233);

    
    echo get_class($entity) . ' ' . $entity->id . "\n";    i tried both, as you can see above...  findOneById  and findOneBy(array)   i think its the id is clashing with the all entities extending it....    ( Actions id field )